# Option to use wild card in 'CREATE Partition function' for the datetime columns?

Tags: sql-server, windows, datetime, partitioning

I want to partition first five days of the month.
Following is the way I achieved it.

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [pf_sampleTable](datetime) AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES ( 
  N'2019-12-01T00:00:00.000'
  , N'2019-12-02T00:00:00.000'
  , N'2019-12-03T00:00:00.000'
  , N'2019-12-04T00:00:00.000'
  , N'2019-12-05T00:00:00.000'
)
GO
```

In this technique there should be an update operation to define new time frames every month.

I was wondering if we could use something like a wild card in the datetime fields.

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [pf_sampleTable](datetime) AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (  
  N'%-01T00:00:00.000'
  , N'%-02T00:00:00.000'
  , N'%-03T00:00:00.000'
  , N'%-04T00:00:00.000'
  , N'%-05T00:00:00.000'
)
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

`CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION` DDL creates static partitions. Although one can specify expressions for the partition boundaries that are evaluated when the statement is run, these are not evaluated afterwards. It is necessary to `ALTER` the function to create or drop partitions after creation.

Consider scheduling a daily job to execute the needed script (and perhaps remove old partitions) as desired.

I suggest a `RANGE RIGHT` function when partitioning on temporal types that have a time component so that values that are exactly midnight don't end up in the wrong partition. The example below will create future date partitions 2 days in advance to avoid expensive data movement when splitting partitions.

```
--initial 5 boundaries
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PF_DateTime(datetime) AS
    RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES(
      NULL -- (dates outside expected range)
    , N'2019-12-01T00:00:00.000'
    , N'2019-12-02T00:00:00.000'
    , N'2019-12-03T00:00:00.000'
    , N'2019-12-04T00:00:00.000'
    , N'2019-12-05T00:00:00.000'
);

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME PS_DateTime AS
    PARTITION PF_DateTime ALL TO ([PRIMARY]);

--run this after midnight on 2019-12-04 to create the 2019-12-06 boundary
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME PS_DateTime
    NEXT USED [PRIMARY];
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION PF_DateTime()
    SPLIT RANGE(CAST(DATEADD(day, 2, GETDATE()) AS date));
```

See [table partitioning best practices](https://www.dbdelta.com/table-partitioning-best-practices/) for more information.